# Identify rolling means sequence in ascending and descending orders from a time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

A set of rolling means generated from a time_series is passed into a DataFrame:

```
rolling_means = {}
fast, slow, bands = 3, 15, 8
steps = np.linspace(fast, slow, bands)

for s in steps:
    X = pd.Series.rolling(time_series, window=int(s), center=False).mean()
    rolling_means[s] = X

rolling_means = pd.DataFrame(rolling_means)
```

The sequence of values in the rolling_means is alternately in ascending or descending order on occasions, but not in any particularly order otherwise. For illustration, the top row (Figure 1) and bottom row (Figure 2) are in descending orders, from left to right:

Figure 1:
[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2:

[image: Figure 2]

How to get the dates and the orders returned when the sequences are perfectly in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, assign the sequence of values to a list in fixed decimals:

```
data_set = np.around(rolling_means[0:].tolist(), decimals=3)
```

Secondly, sort the values in ascending and descending orders in matching decimals:

```
ascending_order = np.around(sorted(data_set), decimals=3)
descending_order = np.around(sorted(data_set, reverse=True), decimals=3)
```

Then check if the data_set matches one of the sorted orders:

```
if np.all(data_set == ascending_order):
    do_statements_ascending

if np.all(data_set == descending_order):
    do_statements_descending
```

Answer (score 1):

For window = n, let's suppose 4,  rolling uses all the data in time_series, and computes the mean for groups of 4; **not separate groups**, for each step it takes a new member, e.g.

data = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

The first step would take 1, 2, 3, 4 
The second step 2, 3, 4, 5

So depending on the data, one should be bigger than the other. Does your data in the time series has an increasing or decreasing order with date? If not, everything is just how it should be.